# SIP client using scripting languages

Tags: protocols, voip, sip

I am looking to implement a SIP VoIP client using any of the scripting languages - either perl, python or ruby or others. I have knowledge of SIP but have not tried anything with scripting languages. I did have a look at perl module Net::SIP for the same and found it to be interesting.

I am looking for something that provides SIP functionality, not media support. Are there any such SIP implementations (like Net::SIP) in the scripting world that are used for this purpose? This is required to do basic functionality testing and not for stress testing.

Answer (score 1):

use [sipp](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/), it relies on xml scripts to send and receive sip messages, it is documented and widely used in telecommuncation industry.

Answer (score 0):

The [sipsak](http://sipsak.org/) tool is commonly used for SIP testing purposes. It's command line based so you could script its operation. If you need to finely control your SIP messages then it's probably not going to be suitable as it's unlikely to expose a sufficient level of control for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two months to wait. then there will be ivrworx RC version http://www.slideshare.net/borisusun/ivr-worx :) Also you can help with development.